# Deleting tempo events from AKSequencer

Tags: audiokit, aksequencer

I need to delete all tempo events from an AKSequencer instance but I can't find a way to do it.

I tried to use the clearRange() method as shown below but I'm not sure it is the right way because it won't work:

```
var sequencer = AKSequencer()

// successfully adding a few tempo events with addTempoEventAt(tempo bpm: Double, position: AKDuration)

...

// trying to remove them

let sequenceLength = sequencer.length
sequencer.clearRange(start: AKDuration(beats: 0.0), duration: sequenceLength)
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: What behavior did you get, and what behavior were you actually expecting?

Comment: I need to rearrange bars with different tempos and time signatures in a sequence, so what I am trying to do is deleting all the tempo events and re-adding them in the new order. What happens, though, is that using clearRange() won't actually delete the tempo events, as @c_booth said, so I end up with both the old tempo events and the new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `clearRange()` removes note events and meta events but, as you observed, it does *not* remove tempo events (the next version of the docs will make this explicit - thank you for catching this).  `AKSequencer` has a private `clearTempoEvents` method called internally by the `setTempo()` method, so you can use `setTempo()` to clear all the existing tempo events.  Of course, after removing the existing tempo events, this will also add a new tempo event at the start of the sequence with the tempo you include as an argument.

So it won't exactly give you a sequence with no tempo events - but a sequence needs a tempo and with no tempo events it will default to 120 - so forcing you to be explicit about the starting tempo isn't such a bad thing.  Anyway, unless you really need for there to be absolutely no tempo events, `setTempo()` should do the trick for clearing all existing tempo events in the sequence.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for, though now I am thinking: what if you need to delete only one tempo event in the middle of a sequence? The only way is to delete all tempo events and re-add them without the unwanted one?

Comment: That's basically right, unless you want to start working directly with the CoreMIDI's C API. You could make a feature request about deleting single events if you needed it - but the cleanest way to implement it would still probably involve 1) iterating through the tempo track to get a record of the current tempo events 2) clearing the existing events, 3) re-inserting the old events with the unwanted ones filtered out.